# Ajax call not passing data to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

Been searching for hours...probably something obvious I miss.

My controller don't get the data

Been doing several workarounds passing data differently but nothing works

Here is my JS :

```
 $('#cfr_btn').on('click', function () {

            if (team_id[team_reference.indexOf(document.getElementById("cfr_team1_tag").value)] != null && team_id[team_reference.indexOf(document.getElementById("cfr_team2_tag").value)] != null && team_id[team_reference.indexOf(document.getElementById("cfr_team1_tag").value)] != team_id[team_reference.indexOf(document.getElementById("cfr_team2_tag").value)]) {
                var this_confront = new Object();
                this_confront.id_team1 = team_id[team_reference.indexOf(document.getElementById("cfr_team1_tag").value)];
                this_confront.id_team2 = team_id[team_reference.indexOf(document.getElementById("cfr_team2_tag").value)];

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Champ/TeamConfront',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: JSON.stringify(this_confront),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        if (response != null) {
                            alert(response);
                        } else {
                            alert("Something went wrong");
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }


        });
```

and here is my method

```
        public class Confrontation
        {
            public int id_team1 { get; set; }
            public int id_team2 { get; set; }
           
        }

    public JsonResult TeamConfront(Confrontation confront)
        {
            IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
  .AddEnvironmentVariables()
  .Build();

            string connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("SQLConnection");
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            List<GameModel> cfrList = new();
            int team1 = confront.id_team1;
            int team2 = confront.id_team2;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetTeamConfrontations", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_team1", team1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_team2", team2);
            SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sd.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                cfrList.Add(
                    new GameModel
                    {
                        id_game = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_game"]),
                        id_season = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_season"]),
                        game_status = Convert.ToInt32(dr["g_status"]),
                        g_team1 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["g_team1"]),
                        g_team2 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["g_team2"]),
                        g_score1 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["g_score1"]),
                        g_score2 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["g_score2"]),
                        g_ot = Convert.ToInt32(dr["g_ot"]),
                        g_pen1 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["g_pen1"]),
                        g_pen2 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["g_pen2"]),
                        day_number = Convert.ToInt32(dr["day_number"]),
                        g_date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["g_date"]),
                        g_po = Convert.ToInt32(dr["g_po"]),
                        g_po_phase = Convert.ToInt32(dr["g_po_phase"]),
                        g_po_number = Convert.ToInt32(dr["g_po_number"]),
                    });
            }

            return Json(cfrList);
        }
```

Everything ok except that confront is always empty (and cfrList too consequently)

Been trying with fixed team1 and team2 and it works.

tried also to pass the data like that :

data: '{"id_team1":"' + team_id[team_reference.indexOf(document.getElementById("cfr_team1_tag").value) + '","id_team2":"' + team_id[team_reference.indexOf(document.getElementById("cfr_team2_tag").value)+ '"}'

Please note team_id and team_reference are JS arrays defined above in the code.

Comment: Solved by adding [FromBody] in the Method declaration like that :

        public JsonResult TeamConfront([FromBody]Confrontation confront)